# How to write unit test cases for UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, viewcontroller

Specifically , i want to check the IBOutlets , but by using

```
var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCID") as UIViewController
```

the IBOutlets are nil .

Answer (score 1):

The view controller's `view` property has to be accessed before the view is loaded and the outlets connected.

```
let view = vc.view
```

Will do it, or you can present the view controller on screen (this will also cause viewWill/DidAppear to be called) by setting it as the window's root view controller.

Comment: vc.loadView() did it for me , but i was stuck at typecasting it to custom controller , i have added the solved solution .

Answer (score 0):

we have to add bundle as   NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType) instead of nil .

```
  func testClientsStoryBoard(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "abc", bundle:  NSBundle(forClass:  self.dynamicType))
        var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("abcVC") as abcViewController
        vc.loadView()
        XCTAssertNotNil(vc.outletName,"Not Nil")

}
```

Comment: If you needed to do that then the view controller itself would have been nil, not just the outlets. That information wasn't in your question